# How to read a PEM RSA private key from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, rsa

I've got an `RSA` private key in `PEM` format, is there a straight forward way to read that from .NET and instantiate an `RSACryptoServiceProvider` to decrypt data encrypted with the corresponding public key?

Comment: There are quite a few answers here, but please note that PEM is not a specific format of the private key. It is basically a wrapper to convert a binary encoded private key into text - a so called ASCII armor. Now the format inside can be a PKCS#1 formatted private key (just the private key without indication that it is an RSA key), a private key in PKCS#8 format that isn't encrypted (only "inner" PKCS#8) or a PKCS#8 private key that is wrapped using a key or passphrase. That leaves the reader with choosing the right answer for each 3 possibilities.

Comment: If it is a PKCS#1 private key then the PEM then it should have "RSA PRIVATE KEY" in the header. If it is PKCS#8 then it just reads "PRIVATE KEY" - as the algorithm is in the binary encoding anyway. And if it is password protected then you generally expect some parameters to follow the initial header line, although this is unfortunately strictly optional.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

#### Update 03/03/2021

.NET 5 now supports this out of the box.

To try the code snippet below, generate a keypair and encrypt some text at http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/

```
var privateKey = @"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
{ the full PEM private key } 
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

var rsa = RSA.Create();
rsa.ImportFromPem(privateKey.ToCharArray());

var decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(
    Convert.FromBase64String("{ base64-encoded encrypted string }"), 
    RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1
);

// this will print the original unencrypted string
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes));
```

#### Original answer

I solved, thanks. In case anyone's interested, [bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) did the trick, just took me some time due to lack of knowledge from on my side and documentation. This is the code:

```
var bytesToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String("la0Cz.....D43g=="); // string to decrypt, base64 encoded
 
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair; 
 
using (var reader = File.OpenText(@"c:\myprivatekey.pem")) // file containing RSA PKCS1 private key
    keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair) new PemReader(reader).ReadObject(); 
 
var decryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
decryptEngine.Init(false, keyPair.Private); 
 
var decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptEngine.ProcessBlock(bytesToDecrypt, 0, bytesToDecrypt.Length));
```

Comment: @WildJoe: Either an inflated habitat for monarchs, or www.bouncycastle.org ;)

Comment: what about with a password protected cert?

Comment: new PemReader(reader)
After this, PemReader cames null, I could not understand it, do you have an  idea about that,Normally pem has no problem and it works..

Comment: @Simone I tried your method and I keep getting ```input too large for RSA cipher.``` error message. My key length in Base64 is 1588 chars and length of cipher text in Base64 is 512 chars  (384 bytes). Can you please help with this?

Comment: @KhurramMajeed RSA is not designed to encrypt long messages, it's used to encrypt the secret that the long message is encrypted with by a symmetric algorithm like AES.

In other words, if I want to encrypt a very long message I will create a secret, use the secret to AES encrypt the long message, and use RSA to encrypt the secret and send the two encrypted strings together to the recipient.

Comment: In my case, the RSA class did not have `.ImportFromPem()` method. Here is a link which covers `.ImportRSAPrivateKey()` method. [https://vcsjones.dev/key-formats-dotnet-3/](https://vcsjones.dev/key-formats-dotnet-3/)

Comment: Now even import from encrypted is possible e.g. with `System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.ImportFromEncryptedPem`

Comment: Updated answer worked for me on my local machine, but for some reason threw an exception with the message `The system cannot find the file specified.` on the `rsa.ImportFromPem()` line. In order to solve it, I had to give the keys as XML values. To generate XML from PEM files, you can use this if you don't want to do it with online generators. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69711270/11858000

Comment: You sir deserve all the upvotes in the world, answering your own question after 13 years, helping poor me having the same question in 2022

Comment: What is ""{ base64-encoded encrypted string }")" ? I don't get this.

Answer (score 36):

With respect to easily importing the RSA private key, without using 3rd party code such as BouncyCastle, I think the answer is "No, not with a PEM of the private key alone."

However, as alluded to above by Simone, you can simply combine the PEM of the private key (*.key) and the certificate file using that key (*.crt) into a *.pfx file which can then be easily imported.

To generate the PFX file from the command line:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in a.crt -inkey a.key -export -out a.pfx
```

Then use normally with the .NET certificate class such as:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

X509Certificate2 combinedCertificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\path\to\file.pfx");
```

Now you can follow the example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx) for encrypting and decrypting via RSACryptoServiceProvider:

I left out that for decrypting you would need to import using the PFX password and the Exportable flag.  (see: [BouncyCastle RSAPrivateKey to .NET RSAPrivateKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949727/bouncycastle-rsaprivatekey-to-net-rsaprivatekey))

```
X509KeyStorageFlags flags = X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable;
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("my.pfx", "somepass", flags);

RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
RSAParameters rsaParam = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
```

Comment: There are so many examples that assume we want to carry the baggage of a command-line tool, specifically, openssl...I want/need a solution that's completely programmatic. Further, .NET Standard 2.1 (aka .NET Core 3.0+/5.0) are not available for the environment I am in.

Comment: The thing that angers me about this it that I can put the pem cert and key files into appsettings.json and it works. Yet, I can't so the same in code?

Answer (score 33):

You might take a look at [JavaScience's](http://www.jensign.com/) source for [OpenSSLKey](https://gist.github.com/njmube/edc64bb2f7599d33ca5a)

There's code in there that does exactly what you want to do.

In fact, they have a lot of crypto source code [available here](http://www.jensign.com/cryptoutils/index.html).

---

Source code snippet:

```
//------- Parses binary ans.1 RSA private key; returns RSACryptoServiceProvider  ---
public static RSACryptoServiceProvider DecodeRSAPrivateKey(byte[] privkey)
{
        byte[] MODULUS, E, D, P, Q, DP, DQ, IQ ;

        // ---------  Set up stream to decode the asn.1 encoded RSA private key  ------
        MemoryStream  mem = new MemoryStream(privkey) ;
        BinaryReader binr = new BinaryReader(mem) ;    //wrap Memory Stream with BinaryReader for easy reading
        byte bt = 0;
        ushort twobytes = 0;
        int elems = 0;
        try {
                twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
                if (twobytes == 0x8130) //data read as little endian order (actual data order for Sequence is 30 81)
                        binr.ReadByte();        //advance 1 byte
                else if (twobytes == 0x8230)
                        binr.ReadInt16();       //advance 2 bytes
                else
                        return null;

                twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
                if (twobytes != 0x0102) //version number
                        return null;
                bt = binr.ReadByte();
                if (bt !=0x00)
                        return null;


                //------  all private key components are Integer sequences ----
                elems = GetIntegerSize(binr);
                MODULUS = binr.ReadBytes(elems);

                elems = GetIntegerSize(binr);
                E = binr.ReadBytes(elems) ;

                elems = GetIntegerSize(binr);
                D = binr.ReadBytes(elems) ;

                elems = GetIntegerSize(binr);
                P = binr.ReadBytes(elems) ;

                elems = GetIntegerSize(binr);
                Q = binr.ReadBytes(elems) ;

                elems = GetIntegerSize(binr);
                DP = binr.ReadBytes(elems) ;

                elems = GetIntegerSize(binr);
                DQ = binr.ReadBytes(elems) ;

                elems = GetIntegerSize(binr);
                IQ = binr.ReadBytes(elems) ;

                Console.WriteLine("showing components ..");
                if (verbose) {
                        showBytes("\nModulus", MODULUS) ;
                        showBytes("\nExponent", E);
                        showBytes("\nD", D);
                        showBytes("\nP", P);
                        showBytes("\nQ", Q);
                        showBytes("\nDP", DP);
                        showBytes("\nDQ", DQ);
                        showBytes("\nIQ", IQ);
                }

                // ------- create RSACryptoServiceProvider instance and initialize with public key -----
                RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                RSAParameters RSAparams = new RSAParameters();
                RSAparams.Modulus =MODULUS;
                RSAparams.Exponent = E;
                RSAparams.D = D;
                RSAparams.P = P;
                RSAparams.Q = Q;
                RSAparams.DP = DP;
                RSAparams.DQ = DQ;
                RSAparams.InverseQ = IQ;
                RSA.ImportParameters(RSAparams);
                return RSA;
        }
        catch (Exception) {
                return null;
        }
        finally {
                binr.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: Tried, doesn't work, and didn't take the time to go through the code yet, I'd hope there was a simpler solution.

Comment: Could you give details on what failed? I took a look at the code, and it seems like it should work. Perhaps you could even post the PEM-file? (If you have a non-sensitive one).

Comment: i just found this answer cross-linked from [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1162519/12597). Now that i see that it's actual code files, and they're literally just decoding the ASN.1 encoded data, this answer deserves more +1.  (They really shouldn't call themselves `JavaScience`)

Comment: It worked for my scenario, which is using an RSA private key encrypted with DES3 passphrase.  But, code is messy; has calls to Console.ReadLine and WriteLine; requires user interaction for entering passphase etc.  Needs a rewrite to be used as a proper library but it works!

Comment: This also worked for me, if anyone wants to see a fully working code sample, here is one for a project where a PHP script creates a key in the PEM format and sends it to C#, which then converts it to XML using the above linked library: http://csharp-tricks-en.blogspot.de/2015/04/rsa-with-c-and-php.html

Comment: Took the javascience code(file name: opensslkey.cs) and builded to find an error, which could simply be commented out. That line of source doesn't seem to influence the output.

Comment: Harvested javascience's code for specific functions related to private key in a pub/priv key combo generated in PHP -- worked like a charm.  I would upvote 1000x if I could for being that one guy who isn't out promoting 'Bouncy Castle' or other bloatware libs.   Many thanks !!

Comment: I've found working links and edited them in to the answer, but still - this answer as it stands is very misleading and would be more helpful if it included the entire code sample. I spent ages trying to decode a PEM assuming the `privkey` in the example you posted was the entire base64 decoded content from ----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY, but it is not

Answer (score 4):

The stuff between the

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----
```

and

```
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

is the base64 encoding of a PKCS#8 PrivateKeyInfo (unless it says RSA ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY in which case it is a EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo).

It is not that hard to decode manually, but otherwise your best bet is to P/Invoke to [CryptImportPKCS8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380208(VS.85).aspx).

---

**Update:** The **[CryptImportPKCS8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380208%28VS.85%29.aspx)** function is no longer available for use as of Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista. Instead, use the **[PFXImportCertStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387314%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** function.

Answer (score 4):

ok, Im using mac to generate my self signed keys. Here is the working method I used.

I created a shell script to speed up my key generation.

genkey.sh

```
#/bin/sh

ssh-keygen -f host.key
openssl req -new -key host.key -out request.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 99999 -in request.csr -signkey host.key -out server.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey host.key -in server.crt -out private_public.p12 -name "SslCert"
openssl base64 -in private_public.p12 -out Base64.key
```

add the +x execute flag to the script

```
chmod +x genkey.sh
```

then call genkey.sh

```
./genkey.sh
```

I enter a password (important to include a password at least for the export at the end)

```
Enter pass phrase for host.key:
Enter Export Password:   {Important to enter a password here}
Verifying - Enter Export Password: { Same password here }
```

I then take everything in Base64.Key and put it into a string named sslKey

```
private string sslKey = "MIIJiAIBA...................................." +
                        "......................ETC...................." +
                        "......................ETC...................." +
                        "......................ETC...................." +
                        ".............ugICCAA=";
```

I then used a lazy load Property getter to get my X509 Cert with a private key.

```
X509Certificate2 _serverCertificate = null;
X509Certificate2 serverCertificate{
    get
    {
        if (_serverCertificate == null){
            string pass = "Your Export Password Here";
            _serverCertificate = new X509Certificate(Convert.FromBase64String(sslKey), pass, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        }
        return _serverCertificate;
    }
}
```

I wanted to go this route because I am using .net 2.0 and Mono on mac and I wanted to use vanilla Framework code with no compiled libraries or dependencies.

My final use for this was the SslStream to secure TCP communication to my app

```
SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(serverCertificate, false, SslProtocols.Tls, true);
```

I hope this helps other people.

**NOTE**

Without a password I was unable to correctly unlock the private key for export.

Answer (score 4):

I've tried [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/251757) for PEM-encoded PKCS#8 RSA private key and it resulted in `PemException` with `malformed sequence in RSA private key` message. The reason is that `Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader` seems to only support PKCS#1 private keys.

I was able to get the private key by switching to `Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.IO.Pem.PemReader` (note that type names match!) like this

```
private static RSAParameters GetRsaParameters(string rsaPrivateKey)
{
    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rsaPrivateKey);
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
        {
            var pemReader = new Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.IO.Pem.PemReader(sr);
            var pem = pemReader.ReadPemObject();
            var privateKey = PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(pem.Content);

            return DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(privateKey as RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Developers who still have code in Framework <=4.8. I did find this as a solution to all the trouble caused by PKCS#8.
I would suggest to have a look at this " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462064/associate-a-private-key-with-the-x509certificate2-class-in-net#answer-72742320 " so that you will get a better idea.

Answer (score 3):

I've created the PemUtils library that does exactly that. The code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/huysentruitw/pem-utils) and can be installed from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=pemutils):

```
PM> Install-Package PemUtils
```

or if you only want a DER converter:

```
PM> Install-Package DerConverter
```

Usage for reading a RSA key from PEM data:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
using (var reader = new PemReader(stream))
{
    var rsaParameters = reader.ReadRsaKey();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For people who don't want to use Bouncy, and are trying some of the code included in other answers, I've found that the code works MOST of the time, but trips up on some RSA private strings, such as the one I've included below. By looking at the bouncy code, I tweaked the code provided by wprl to

```
    RSAparams.D = ConvertRSAParametersField(D, MODULUS.Length);
    RSAparams.DP = ConvertRSAParametersField(DP, P.Length);
    RSAparams.DQ = ConvertRSAParametersField(DQ, Q.Length);
    RSAparams.InverseQ = ConvertRSAParametersField(IQ, Q.Length);

    private static byte[] ConvertRSAParametersField(byte[] bs, int size)
    {
        if (bs.Length == size)
            return bs;

        if (bs.Length > size)
            throw new ArgumentException("Specified size too small", "size");

        byte[] padded = new byte[size];
        Array.Copy(bs, 0, padded, size - bs.Length, bs.Length);
        return padded;
    }

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: for me who uses cryptography about once every 2-3 years I have no idea how to get the length values for your method. would love to get something along the lines of PemReader that just computes those themself, or at least some explanation

Answer (score 1):

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203099.aspx

under Cryptography Application Block.

Don't know if you will get your answer, but it's worth a try.

**Edit after Comment**.

Ok then check this code.

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;


public static string DecryptEncryptedData(stringBase64EncryptedData, stringPathToPrivateKeyFile) { 
    X509Certificate2 myCertificate; 
    try{ 
        myCertificate = new X509Certificate2(PathToPrivateKeyFile); 
    } catch{ 
        throw new CryptographicException("Unable to open key file."); 
    } 

    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaObj; 
    if(myCertificate.HasPrivateKey) { 
         rsaObj = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)myCertificate.PrivateKey; 
    } else 
        throw new CryptographicException("Private key not contained within certificate."); 

    if(rsaObj == null) 
        return String.Empty; 

    byte[] decryptedBytes; 
    try{ 
        decryptedBytes = rsaObj.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(Base64EncryptedData), false); 
    } catch { 
        throw new CryptographicException("Unable to decrypt data."); 
    } 

    //    Check to make sure we decrpyted the string 
   if(decryptedBytes.Length == 0) 
        return String.Empty; 
    else 
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes); 
}
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't support any asymmetric algorithms.

Comment: This code can't load a PEM rsa private key, it needs a certificate file based on that key, which can be generated, but I would like to avoid that step.

Comment: Ok, then tell me where do you have your private key?

Comment: If you read my reply to the previous answer you'll see that I already tried and it didn't work.

Comment: Didn't noticed, I removed the last part since it's equal to the first answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
private static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String privateKeyPath) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        try (FileReader keyReader = new FileReader(privateKeyPath);
             PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(keyReader)) {

            PemObject pemObject = pemReader.readPemObject();
            byte[] content = pemObject.getContent();
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(content);
            return (PrivateKey) factory.generatePrivate(privKeySpec);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?