# Converting PGP public keys to RSA Public key XML Format

Tags: c#, .net, rsa, pgp

I am faced with a problem on converting PGP Public keys to RSA Public Key format. Following public key in PGP format that need to be converted to XML format.

Please help me, if any of you had encountered such scenarios.

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.1 (MingW32)
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=+Q6Q
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

This need to be converted to RSAKeyValue XML format like the one below.

```
<RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>151Vw6Kq51bpblahblahblahWCkPmD345ncclzFrmeb9fjpE+B6VsIAqP3kahu00p33BmFpDpXOcgi uRC2En0HoGqyZB9ifvNlPhT7flZ1uVuC9JtywG3FmYRsqbpJuT7VTIAHYExU6T/FyRuyIbhdUVwhue7ARaObsEWszE1IoM7+XcYYs=</Modulus>
    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
    <P>+7OU6YErvfk84O/2bX5s2753xE+pdiyJl3j8gy4zMh4UKeKVhyxgSJJCvNTl9XVIya6xnCWPkHVy8ylNqyLiHQ==</P>
    <Q>20v7/nODe/jKcbsiYEwzGXp0ZyiG17JqzOBKrDFu6bwPiAEHzZln0CYfUn0E hJdCmetaq9WFXk27mbK3Z6aBxw==</Q>
    <DP>RpoN6B26dlRGFlZZCkePI2he0esCfsppYdqnAejgpWs4 frM2/C6fZ1vXan5RbrOSUjg1S7ZhecToFHr+dUWYpQ== </DP>
    <DQ>ayaHbF7YwfxgPo3nUBIrbamNstH0gPQmhxCYq+ZDgWV oWVXXkDgCp4vZBh8b1AVsf3SmCwv7bIaiwYi3YKfVBQ==</DQ
    <InverseQ>YjvieMYPEDdUHqSZRWAsFlEESd3NczFCrbBaS HzbsbOZeDrccvUfoOP2jeIhuMt0qQwMqXY/NJau9Ldwdx7xNw==</InverseQ>
    <D>wEg6bM5LVSWoQgWpoldz5dQWfQjqQVc8WzKpDA HQ8ejsm0ug4ZwRcRRnKZs3o7OTsiAJCfjqT9ij1gKMoeLrXIM1 RDOcAYBxI0qwWdRrr3sbar7ntMYmy4tlTTf8/G+ypw+CJi1gz2umswcx4MHhNTUGTUHSmjEjDTFfh3sW64k= </D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this 1:1 like you want.  They're different encryption standards, using entirely different keys with different components.  Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @DarkBobG: I came read similar reviews from other forums too. Thanks for your time and +1 for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got what I was looking for from this SO post.

[BouncyCastle RSAPrivateKey to .NET RSAPrivateKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949727/bouncycastle-rsaprivatekey-to-net-rsaprivatekey)

Answer (score 5):

While generally it *is* possible to extract key material from an OpenPGP RSA key (note that OpenPGP also gets use of DSS/Elgamal keys), your example is somewhat inconsistent, as it states *public* OpenPGP key and *private* RSA/XML key. So I think it makes sense to sort these things out before you continue (as it is impossible to get private RSA key from a public RSA key).

Comment: Strictly speaking it isn't impossible, it just takes a bit of time, that's all :)

Comment: @KenJhonson: What I tried to convey was to convert OpenPGP public key to RSA public key XML format. By change I  pasted the private key XML text. Thanks for pointing out. So what I could understand from your response is that, its possible to retrieve public keys with some custom code.

Comment: @AbrahamJP: Yes. The structure of OpenPGP keys is defined in RFC 4880. Basically, you should do the following: 1) decode the key if you got it in base64 encoded form, 2) read the contents of the key file packet-by-packet, searching for RSA key and/or RSA subkey packet (depending on the requirements of your task), 3) extract n and e values from it, 4) envelope them into an appropriate XML structure. Probably some OpenPGP API vendors offer such functionality... Yet I can't say that this is a complex task indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions.