# RSA integration between c# and php

Tags: c#, php, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I want to send encrypted data to php as part of a c# project. The php page should decrypt the data and perform some operation on it ,then encrypt it again, and return it back to the c# application.
There is an issue with how the kyes look:
rsa private key:

> uGUskwU/GVS1HjBVBa9ECPDRH04fH............

php private key:

> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIICXAIBAAKBgQDARufsW5Z9I+P96RdfDEq8r5XYaC ......

How can I integrate the two, or is there another class in C# I can use besides cryptography which would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/

Generate keys:

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 1024
openssl rsa -in private.pem -out public.pem -outform PEM -pubout
```

Copy to php:

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$privateKey="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
$publicKey="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDr5KvAc6JX22BdpsfQbWam8rjk
wJzTC954XQzhLOPeGiAGfkPmCLYhBrmxZN6NxiseivpN9yzrRjYeccr+s3A/8q1E
bdhmmM4+AxdNzATEsUxL//MSVXCaoJhGOfXswokFT8HQod9M6VMmuyDaw9iEorLa
vV6J/nCmq2HIutcbbwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($publicKey); // public key

$plaintext = 'I am a secret.. shhhhhh.';

$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
$ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($plaintext);

$rsa->loadKey($privateKey); // private key
echo $rsa->decrypt($ciphertext);
?>
```

You can use different keys, but the php code must encrypt data using the C# public key and the C# code must use the php public key to encrypt data posted to the php code.

You can also have only two keys, one private and one public and use on both sides.

Take a look at this answer of doing this on the C# side: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1162519/2715306
And this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/251757/2715306