# SslStream AuthenticateAsServer failed with "Server certificate Private Key unavailable." exception on Mono

Tags: c#, ssl, mono, x509

Basically what I want to do is run the MSDN example about [SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on Mono.

I keep getting the exception: *Exception: The authentication or decryption has failed.
Inner exception: Server certificate Private Key unavailable.*

I assume the code should be fine, and that my problem is certificate/environment related.

I have tried generating self-singed-certificates with both the OpenSsl toolkit and makecert. I have also installed those certificates with certmgr in the Trust strof off both the user and the machine.

I am out of ideas and have no further clue. Anyone? A step-by-step tutorial would be nice, but anything will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a solution that was suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24863777/2968001).

1. Use the X509Certificate**2** class instead of X509Certificate
2. Embed the private key in the certificate (make a .pfx file)