# Cannot find the requested object. when create X509certificate2

Tags: c#, cryptography, x509certificate

I'm trying to create **X509Certificate2** with `private_key` string using the following code:

```
 byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String(private_key);
 X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(key);
```

When the last line executes the following exception is thrown:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException Cannot find the requested object

Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to initialise the X509Cert with the private key https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148413(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: http://paulstovell.com/blog/x509certificate2 Look at Tip 5.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462064/associate-a-private-key-with-the-x509certificate2-class-in-net

Comment: I tried with the following code:
  X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2 (@ "C:\cygwin\home\ Administrator\private_key.pem"); but still fails

Answer (score 2):

A private key doesn't typically be in the form of an X.509 certificate. You can either find it as PFX or P12 files which you should import into a `X509CertificateCollection` to get the private key as an `X509Certificate` instance.

The other alternative (if the private key you have is in the form of a PFX or P12 file) is to load the private key into the windows local certificate store and then load it using the `X509Store` class which would give you the private key as `X509Certificate` instance.

Since you have a PEM file, then see this [Convert a CERT/PEM certificate to a PFX certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808669/convert-a-cert-pem-certificate-to-a-pfx-certificate) for how to convert it into a PFX file.