# C# - How to merge private key with certificate

Tags: c#, certificate, x509

Is there a way to add private key to certificate? API of Certificate authority app returns two base64 strings (one with private key, one with certificate without private part). I want to save the Resulting certificate onto smart card.

There are some answers but there are missing libraries or they don't work at all.

Comment: "There are some answers but there are missing libraries or they don't work at all." Why cannot you drill down into those failures? If a library is missing, simply find it.

Comment: I don't think you want to add an un-encrypted key to a document.  The private key is suppose to be sent separate from the message to make is harder for somebody to de-crypt the message.

Comment: Have you tried talking to your CA (about getting a cert with the private key included)?  A certificate is digitally signed by the CA, you can't be messing around with it without messing up the signature.

Answer (score 0):

What about building an X509Certificate2 from it, using e.g. [Associate a private key with the X509Certificate2 class in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462064/associate-a-private-key-with-the-x509certificate2-class-in-net)

then, dump the certificate to PFX using `certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12,"password")`, and dumping the byte[] to disk, and finally, launch:

```
certutil -importPFX <pfxFile> -p password -csp "Microsoft Smart Card Key Storage Provider" ...
```