# dotnet publish ios signing error : ASN1 corrupted data

Tags: ios, .net, certificate, maui, publish

I am trying to publish my .Net MAUI app to ios using dotnet cli.
I use the following command:

```
dotnet publish -f net8.0-ios -c Release -p:ArchiveOnBuild=true -p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64  -p:CodesignKey="Apple Distribution: XXXXXXXXX (123456789)" -p:CodesignProvision="myprofile"
```

I get the following output:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/17.2.8022/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(1805,3): error : ASN1 corrupted data. [/Users/david/RiderProjects/App/App.Mobile/App.Mobile.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
```

It's not the first time I deploy to iOS, I also did Xamarin in the past, so the certificates, profiles and so on are something I already did. I am also able to build and publish the same app from CI/CD pipeline using the same command and certificates without issues. I tested different IDEs and it's the same behavior.

I am running locally on a Mac M1 and I am wondering if this might be the problem. However I didn't find any similar issue related to Mac M1 and maui deployment. I don't have any issue building or testing the app on simulator and have no issues at all publishing for android. It looks related to the signing process but I don't know how to move on with the debug.

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks.

Comment: Looks like your key might not be in the right format? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70132607/1506387

Comment: I tried over again https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/?view=net-maui-8.0 this time generating certificate through vs for mac. Same behavior. Can you be more explicit on how to generate the right format? I don't see any specific option I just follow the docs. I noted one thing though. My "Bundle signing" tab under project properties is not able to show up, no matter what IDE I use. i.e. in VSmac it's totally empty in Rider it's endless loading. I reinstalled in the meantime and same thing :(

Comment: You said you were also able to build and publish the same app from CI/CD pipeline using the same command and certificates without issues.  Are there any differences for the environment settings like the different IDEs or any other differences?