# HTTPS in C# .net framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, linux, https, certificate, httplistener

im trying to make backend in c# on my linux ubuntu server without using apache2 or ngnix. Everything worked fine, until i've tried to make https, i made a certificate and the key, using openssl copied it to /etc/ssl/certs and /etc/ssl/certs

and i wrote this using different stackoverflow questions:

```
            HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
            string certificatePath = "whoisalmo.crt";
            if (!File.Exists(certificatePath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Cannot find certificate file: {certificatePath}");
                return;
            }
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath);
            string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            string[] prefixes = { "https://+:443/", "http://*/" };
            foreach (string s in prefixes)
                listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
            listener.Start();
            while(true) 
            {
            ...
            }
```

when i start this, the http works, but https doesnt, I wont get error in the app but when i try to access the website it says connection was reseted.

i tried

- Making new certificate
- rebooting after coping the crt and key..
- opening firewall on pc and portforwarding on router

Comment: Any reason to use the old Net. Framework and not something derived from Net. Core?Something that is explicitly meant to be cross plattform and is tested to also run on Linux?

Comment: Are you sure you have a complete certificate here. As far as i know crt is only the public key and there should be a ".key" file also. And as you talking about a framework not intended for Linux the X509Certificate2 class is presumably not capable of handling the pair. More common on Windows would have been a "pem" file.

Comment: The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462064/associate-a-private-key-with-the-x509certificate2-class-in-net) might give you a hint.

Comment: first ive tried .net8 but that didnt work either, ive never worked with the certificates so I dont know if it was bcause of it but ill try to make the .pfx..
Ive moved to ASP.NET, it has https so its win, i will try the link you've sent me, it seems it should work.Thank you