# Failed to import RSA private key: "Bad Version of provider"

Tags: c#, rsa

I have a random private key (`"C:\tmp\private.key"`):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICXgIBAAKBgQDHikastc8+I81zCg/qWW8dMr8mqvXQ3qbPAmu0RjxoZVI47tvs
kYlFAXOf0sPrhO2nUuooJngnHV0639iTTEYG1vckNaW2R6U5QTdQ5Rq5u+uV3pMk
7w7Vs4n3urQ6jnqt2rTXbC1DNa/PFeAZatbf7ffBBy0IGO0zc128IshYcwIDAQAB
AoGBALTNl2JxTvq4SDW/3VH0fZkQXWH1MM10oeMbB2qO5beWb11FGaOO77nGKfWc
bYgfp5Ogrql4yhBvLAXnxH8bcqqwORtFhlyV68U1y4R+8WxDNh0aevxH8hRS/1X5
031DJm1JlU0E+vStiktN0tC3ebH5hE+1OxbIHSZ+WOWLYX7JAkEA5uigRgKp8ScG
auUijvdOLZIhHWq7y5Wz+nOHUuDw8P7wOTKU34QJAoWEe771p9Pf/GTA/kr0BQnP
QvWUDxGzJwJBAN05C6krwPeryFKrKtjOGJIniIoY72wRnoNcdEEs3HDRhf48YWFo
riRbZylzzzNFy/gmzT6XJQTfktGqq+FZD9UCQGIJaGrxHJgfmpDuAhMzGsUsYtTr
iRox0D1Iqa7dhE693t5aBG010OF6MLqdZA1CXrn5SRtuVVaCSLZEL/2J5UcCQQDA
d3MXucNnN4NPuS/L9HMYJWD7lPoosaORcgyK77bSSNgk+u9WSjbH1uYIAIPSffUZ
bti+jc1dUg5wb+aeZlgJAkEAurrpmpqj5vg087ZngKfFGR5rozDiTsK5DceTV97K
a3Y+Nzl+XWTxDBWk4YPh2ZlKv402hZEfWBYxUDn5ZkH/bw==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I tried to use the `RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportCspBlob` to import it but it failed with the error:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Bad Version of
>   provider.

Full stack trace:

```
Failed: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Bad Version of provider.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._ImportCspBlob(Byte[] keyBlob, SafeProvHandle hProv, CspProviderFlags flags, SafeKeyHandle& hKey)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.ImportCspBlobHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, Byte[] keyBlob, Boolean publicOnly, CspParameters& parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportCspBlob(Byte[] keyBlob)
   at ConsoleApplication3.Program.DecodeRSA(Byte[] data, Int32 c_data) in C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\myproj\ConsoleApplication3\Program.cs:line 28
   at ConsoleApplication3.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\myproj\ConsoleApplication3\Program.cs:line 14
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static public byte[] privateKey;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                privateKey = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\tmp\private.key");
                DecodeRSA(privateKey);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed: {0}", e);
            }
        }

        static public void DecodeRSA(byte[] data)
        {
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                rsa.ImportCspBlob(Program.privateKey);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are expecting. You appear to be trying to decrypt the first byte of your private key using your private key.

Comment: It stops before on the line `rsa.ImportCspBlob(Program.privateKey);`. I removed the rest of the code. You I want to understand why the above line fail.

Comment: @E235 can you edit and add complete stack trace? It helps us give a solution.

Comment: It fails because you are just reading the textual content of the private key file as a byte array but this is not compatible with the format that `ImportCspBlob`.

Comment: Snuil Dhappadhule, I added stack trace. @spodger, any idea what is the format of the private key should be?

Comment: As you might expect, `ImportCSPBlob()` imports a key that is in "CSP blob" format, which is naturally an undocumented proprietary Microsoft format. You key is not even close to the right format.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to the @Topaco answer, I understood that I need to find the CSP blob and like he mentioned, it is undocumented.

So I just used `byte[] a = rsa.ExportCspBlob(true);` to get it.
I converted the bytes to base64 and this is a correct key format in base64 that worked for me:

```
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
```

It is important to mentioned that I just need that this function will pass successfully because I am working on a blackbox application and I can't change the code, I need to provide it with the right input.

Comment: the question is about import and you have explained on export!

Comment: Explain how you imported that value that you exported here, I already had my key in this format, but the importCspBlob still gives a bad provider error.

Answer (score 6):

Your private key has a [PKCS1-PEM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48960291/9014097)-Format. [Private key BLOBs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/SecCrypto/base-provider-key-blobs#private-key-blobs) have another format. As already mentioned in the comments, the formats are very different and cannot be easily converted (see e.g. [here](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/how-to-convert-pem-file-to-a-cryptoapi-compatible-format.aspx)). Of course you can use a PKCS1-PEM-key, but it is not that easy. Here are some options:

*Possibility 1:*

If you use .NET Core 3.0 there is a [direct support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#cryptographic-key-importexport) for reading a PKCS1-key (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53439332/9014097)):

```
byte[] privateKeyPkcs1PEM = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\tmp\private.key"); // PKCS1 - PEM
byte[] privateKeyPkcs1DER = ConvertPKCS1PemToDer(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(privateKeyPkcs1PEM));
RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(privateKeyPkcs1DER, out _);

// use e.g. rsa.Decrypt(...)
```

However, the `ImportRSAPrivateKey`-method can only process the DER-format which is essentially the binary format of the PEM-format (for more details see [here](https://tls.mbed.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48958447/9014097)). Thus, you have to convert the PEM-format into the DER-format with something like

```
private static byte[] ConvertPKCS1PemToDer(string pemContents)
{
    return Convert.FromBase64String(pemContents
        .TrimStart("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----".ToCharArray())
        .TrimEnd("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----".ToCharArray())
        .Replace("\r\n",""));
}
```

Alternatively, OpenSSL can also be used for the [conversion](https://www.poftut.com/convert-der-pem-pem-der-certificate-format-openssl/):

```
openssl rsa -inform PEM -outform DER -in C:\tmp\private.key -out C:\tmp\private.der
```

*Possibility 2:*

You can convert your PKCS1-PEM-key into an PKCS8-DER-key using OpenSSL. The appropriate [command](https://gist.github.com/gtaban/410db2351e52ae36a2a636f3cc6f86ac) is:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform pem -in C:\tmp\private.key -outform der -nocrypt -out C:\tmp\privatepkcs8.der
```

The difference between PKCS1- and PKCS8-format is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48960291/9014097). Then you can import the key with built-in .NET-methods (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48911283/9014097), section *PKCS#8 PrivateKeyInfo*):

```
byte[] privateKeyPkcs8DER = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\tmp\privatepkcs8.der"); // PKCS8 - DER
CngKey cngKey = CngKey.Import(privateKeyPkcs8DER, CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);
RSA rsa = new RSACng(cngKey);

// use e.g. rsa.Decrypt(...)
```

*Possibility 3:*

If third-party-libraries may be used, [BouncyCastle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/251757/9014097) is also a possibility:

```
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\tmp\private.key"); // PKCS1 - PEM
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
Pkcs1Encoding pkcs1Encoding = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

// E.g. decryption
pkcs1Encoding.Init(false, keyPair.Private);
byte[] decrypted = pkcs1Encoding.ProcessBlock(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);
```

*Possibility 4:*

Another possibility is the use of the [`DecodeRSAPrivateKey`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1162519/9014097)-method from [`JavaScience`](https://gist.github.com/stormwild/7887264) which can process a PKCS1-key. However, the `DecodeRSAPrivateKey`-method can only process the DER-format. Thus, you must first manually convert the PEM-format into the DER-format using e.g. `ConvertPKCS1PemToDer` or OpenSSL.

Comment: great stuff but I need to be able to use the function `ImportCspBlob` because this is what is being on some blackbox application I am working on and need to understand how to provide it with the correct private key format. So I need to generate the correct private key format that the function `ImportCspBlob` will work on. I can't replace it.