# Converting byte[] to some implementation of AsymmetricAlgorithm

Tags: c#, .net, security, private-key, xml-signature

I need to convert a byte[] to some implementation of AsymmetricAlgorithm. I am trying to sign a `xml` and I can only get the private key in a byte array. 
I am using the quite good [PKCS11.Net](http://pkcs11net.sourceforge.net/) to access a token, if anyone needs to know.

The class I am using to sign is this: `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml`
The property only asks for AsymmetricAlgorithm : `XmlSignedXml.SigningKey`;

Does anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Check out this thread [How to read a PEM RSA private key from .NET.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243646/how-to-read-a-pem-rsa-private-key-from-net).

Answer (score 0):

Use a library like http://www.bouncycastle.org/ to import this.