# How to get the private key from a separate file?

Tags: c#, openssl, private-key, x509certificate2, public-key

I have an Apache (xampp/wamp) server that provides a SSL connection on port 443.
It uses two certificate files: server.cert and server.key when the latter conains the private key.

I have another server configured to listen to requests on port 843 (flash policy stuff) and response to a certain request with some text reply written in C# which runs separately.

In order to achieve SSL connectivity, i use a flex object called SecureSocket which allowes that, however, it uses the original servers certificate in order to encrypt the request.

My goal is to teach my 843 C# server to decrypt the sent data and encrypt the reply and for this i'm using the X509Certificate object in C#.

However, since the pub and priv keys are on different files, i'm getting FALSE on the following:

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.crt\server.crt");
UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
byte[] byteCert = encoding.GetBytes(text);
X509Certificate2 uberCert = new X509Certificate2();
uberCert.Import(byteCert);
Console.WriteLine("Has privateKey:" + uberCert.HasPrivateKey.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("PrivateKey: \n" + uberCert.PrivateKey);
```

Obviously, the False on uberCert.HasPrivateKey comes from the fact that the private key is on a different file, so my questions are:

1.How can i read the private key using the X509CErtificate2 object?
2.How can i use the public key in order to decrypt the received message and how to re-encrypt it with the private key (in order to send the encrypted response back) ?

Thanks in advance,

Mike.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a small helper NuGet package (based on [opensslkey](http://www.jensign.com/opensslkey/opensslkey.cs)) to create a **X509 certificate based** on **public key** and **private (rsa) key**.

```
// Generate with: openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private.key -out certificate_pub.crt
string certificateText = File.ReadAllText("certificate_pub.crt");
string privateKeyText = File.ReadAllText("private.key");

ICertificateProvider provider = new CertificateFromFileProvider(certificateText, privateKeyText);
X509Certificate2 certificate = provider.Certificate;

// Example: use the PrivateKey from the certificate above for signing a JWT token using Jose.Jwt:
string token = Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, certificate.PrivateKey, JwsAlgorithm.RS256);
```

See [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenSSL.X509Certificate2.Provider) and [Github-project](https://github.com/StefH/OpenSSL-X509Certificate2-Provider) for functionality and code-examples.

Answer (score 0):

The private key is likely [PEM encoded](http://www.faqs.org/qa/qa-14736.html) [PKCS#8](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2130) structure.

The Mono project provides code to read this [format](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Cryptography/PKCS8.cs) (among other) in the [Mono.Security.dll](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security) assembly. This assembly is purely managed and will work on Windows, Linux or OSX.

Answer (score 0):

You can't in straight .NET.

You can either use BouncyCastle (see this answer: [How to read a PEM RSA private key from .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243646/how-to-read-a-pem-rsa-private-key-from-net)) or use a PKCS12 container instead for the username + password, which you can create using OpenSSL's tools from the PEM files.

Comment: Hi @Joe,
I've done the following: `X509Certificate2 uberCert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\xampp\apache\conf\server.pfx","qwe123",X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);` after combining both keys into a single pfx file using openssl. It replies with true if i check whether a private key exists, yet i don't know how use it in order to decipher my not Base64 encoded requests. When using the link you've provided, all i'm getting are exceptions. any tips?