# Using CngKey to Generate RSA key pair in PEM (DKIM compatible) using C#.... similar to "openssl rsa"

Tags: c#, certificate, rsa, pem

Is it possible to generate an RSA key pair, export that into ASN1 format compatible with [DKIM's PEM-like format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11269079/328397), using only C#?

I'd like to reduce my dependencies on 3rd parties, but here are some that I have found

**Bouncy Castle**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/251757

**Cryptography Application Block**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203099.aspx
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/243787

**Win32 PFXImportCertStore**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387314(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387313(v=vs.85)

**Import PEM**

- This code only imports PEM data, but is different from OpenSSL in that it fixes an issue with .NET 4.0 and leading zeros in the key http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162194/Certificates-to-DB-and-Back

**Microsoft's CLR Security enhancements**

- http://clrsecurity.codeplex.com/

**Microsoft CNG**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163389.aspx

Here is code for the Microsoft CNG provider with the .NET dll on codeplex (above)... however I don't know how to export and import both the public and private keys in [DKIM compatible ASN1 format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11269079/328397).

```
     byte[] pkcs8PrivateKey = null;
        byte[] signedData = null;

        CngKey key = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm2.Rsa);
       byte[] exportedPrivateBytes = key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.GenericPrivateBlob);

       string exportedPrivateString= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(exportedPrivateBytes);

        pkcs8PrivateKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exportedPrivateString);

        using (CngKey signingKey = CngKey.Import(pkcs8PrivateKey, CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob))
        {
            using (RSACng rsa = new RSACng(signingKey))
            {
                rsa.SignatureHashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha1;
                signedData = rsa.SignData(dataToSign);
            }
        }
```

**Question**

Are there any direct examples of using Microsoft's libraries (Win32, PFX, or CLR on Codeplex) that illustrate how to create a key pair and export / import those values in PEM format?

Comment: PEM is not really a format, so you'll need to be more specific on why you want 'PEM format', and what you hope to interoperate with.

Comment: @GregS I updated the question. I want ASN1 format that is compatible with the DKIM entry stored in DNS

Comment: This looks like an answer to your question:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dcook/archive/2008/11/25/creating-a-self-signed-certificate-in-c.aspx

Answer (score 2):

So you just need a pkcs8 of the key then.

```
CngKeyCreationParameters ckcParams = new CngKeyCreationParameters()
{
    ExportPolicy = CngExportPolicies.AllowPlaintextExport,
    KeyCreationOptions = CngKeyCreationOptions.None,
    KeyUsage = CngKeyUsages.AllUsages,                
};
ckcParams.Parameters.Add(new CngProperty("Length", BitConverter.GetBytes(2048), CngPropertyOptions.None));

myCngKey = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.Rsa, null, ckcParams);

byte[] privatePlainTextBlob = myCngKey.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(privatePlainTextBlob));
}
```

Now your key pair is contained in the PKCS#8 ASN.1 encoded string.