# How do I use BER encoding with object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.BerConverter.Encode("???", myData)

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, ldap, x509certificate, directoryservices

I need to encode and decode BER data.  .NET has the class `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.BerConverter`

The static method requires me to enter a string in the first parameter as shown below

```
        byte[] oid = { 0x30, 0xD, 0x6, 0x9, 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xF7, 0xD, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x5, 0x0 }; // Object ID for RSA

        var result2 = System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.BerConverter.Decoding("?what goes here?", oid);
```

BER encoding is used in LDAP, Certificates, and is commonplace in many other formats.

I'll be happy with information telling me how to Encode or Decode on this class.  There is nothing on Stack Overflow or the first few pages of Google  (or Bing) regarding this.

**Question**

- How do I convert the byte array above to the corresponding OID using BER decoding?
- How can I parse (or attempt to parse) SubjectPublicKeyInfo ASN.1 data in DER or BER format?
- It seems the DER encoding\decoding classes are internal to the .NET framework.  If so, where are they?  (I'd like to ask connect.microsoft.com to make these members public)

Comment: If this question remains unanswered, I suggest a general purpose TLV parser. The function above seems very specific to DirectoryServices.

Answer (score 6):

> How do I convert the byte array above to the corresponding OID using BER decoding?

After you have extracted the OID byte array, you can convert it to an OID string using `OidByteArrayToString()`. I have included the code below, since I couldn't find a similar function in the .NET libraries.

> How can I parse (or attempt to parse) SubjectPublicKeyInfo ASN.1 data in DER or BER format?

I was not able to find a TLV parser in the .NET SDK either. Below is an implementation of a BER TLV parser, `BerTlv`. Since DER is a subset of BER, parsing will work the same way. Given a BER-TLV `byte[]` array, it will return a list of `BerTlv` objects that support access of sub TLVs.

> It seems the DER encoding\decoding classes are internal to the .NET framework. If so, where are they? (I'd like to ask connect.microsoft.com to make these members public)

Maybe somebody else can answer this question.

**Summary**

Here is an example of how you can use the code provided below. I have used the public key data you provided in your previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11269079/845279). The BerTlv should probably be augmented to support querying like `BerTlv.getValue(rootTlvs, '/30/30/06');`.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string pubkey = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDrEee0Ri4Juz+QfiWYui/E9UGSXau/2P8LjnTD8V4Unn+2FAZVGE3kL23bzeoULYv4PeleB3gfmJiDJOKU3Ns5L4KJAUUHjFwDebt0NP+sBK0VKeTATL2Yr/S3bT/xhy+1xtj4RkdV7fVxTn56Lb4udUnwuxK4V5b5PdOKj/+XcwIDAQAB";
    byte[] pubkeyByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(pubkey);
    List<BerTlv> rootTlvs = BerTlv.parseTlv(pubkeyByteArray);

    BerTlv firstTlv = rootTlvs.Where(tlv => tlv.Tag == 0x30).First();//first sequence (tag 30)
    BerTlv secondTlv = firstTlv.SubTlv.Where(tlv => tlv.Tag == 0x30).First();//second sequence (tag 30)
    BerTlv oid = secondTlv.SubTlv.Where(tlv => tlv.Tag == 0x06).First();//OID tag (tag 30)

    string strOid = OidByteArrayToString(oid.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(strOid);
}
```

Output:

> 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1

**OID Encode/Decode**

```
public static byte[] OidStringToByteArray(string oid)
{
    string[] split = oid.Split('.');
    List<byte> retVal = new List<byte>();

    //root arc
    if (split.Length > 0)
        retVal.Add((byte)(Convert.ToInt32(split[0])*40));

    //first arc
    if (split.Length > 1)
        retVal[0] += Convert.ToByte(split[1]);

    //subsequent arcs
    for (int i = 2; i < split.Length; i++)
    {
        int arc_value = Convert.ToInt32(split[i]);
        Stack<byte> bytes = new Stack<byte>();
        while (arc_value != 0)
        {
            byte val = (byte) ((arc_value & 0x7F) | (bytes.Count == 0 ? 0x0:0x80));
            arc_value >>= 7;
            bytes.Push(val);
        }
        retVal.AddRange(bytes);
    }
    return retVal.ToArray();
}

public static string OidByteArrayToString(byte[] oid)
{
    StringBuilder retVal = new StringBuilder();

    //first byte
    if (oid.Length > 0)
        retVal.Append(String.Format("{0}.{1}", oid[0] / 40, oid[0] % 40));

    // subsequent bytes
    int current_arc = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < oid.Length; i++)
    {
        current_arc = (current_arc <<= 7) | oid[i] & 0x7F;

        //check if last byte of arc value
        if ((oid[i] & 0x80) == 0)
        {
            retVal.Append('.');
            retVal.Append(Convert.ToString(current_arc));
            current_arc = 0;
        }
    }

    return retVal.ToString();
}
```

**BER-TLV Parser**

```
class BerTlv
{
    private int tag;
    private int length;
    private int valueOffset;
    private byte[] rawData;
    private List<BerTlv> subTlv;

    private BerTlv(int tag, int length, int valueOffset, byte[] rawData)
    {
        this.tag = tag;
        this.length = length;
        this.valueOffset = valueOffset;
        this.rawData = rawData;
        this.subTlv = new List<BerTlv>();
    }
    public int Tag
    {
        get { return tag; }
    }
    public byte[] RawData
    {
        get { return rawData; }
    }
    public byte[] Value
    {
        get
        {
            byte[] result = new byte[length];
            Array.Copy(rawData, valueOffset, result, 0, length);
            return result;
        }
    }
    public List<BerTlv> SubTlv
    {
        get { return subTlv; }
    }
    public static List<BerTlv> parseTlv(byte[] rawTlv)
    {
        List<BerTlv> result = new List<BerTlv>();
        parseTlv(rawTlv, result);
        return result;
    }
    private static void parseTlv(byte[] rawTlv, List<BerTlv> result)
    {
        for (int i = 0, start=0; i < rawTlv.Length; start=i)
        {
            //parse Tag
            bool constructed_tlv = (rawTlv[i] & 0x20) != 0;
            bool more_bytes = (rawTlv[i] & 0x1F) == 0x1F;
            while (more_bytes && (rawTlv[++i] & 0x80) != 0) ;
            i++;

            int tag = Util.getInt(rawTlv, start, i-start);

            //parse Length
            bool multiByte_Length = (rawTlv[i] & 0x80) != 0;

            int length = multiByte_Length ? Util.getInt(rawTlv, i+1, rawTlv[i] & 0x1F) : rawTlv[i];
            i = multiByte_Length ? i + (rawTlv[i] & 0x1F) + 1: i + 1;

            i += length;

            byte[] rawData = new byte[i - start];
            Array.Copy(rawTlv, start, rawData, 0, i - start);
            BerTlv tlv = new BerTlv(tag, length, i - length, rawData);
            result.Add(tlv);

            if (constructed_tlv)
                parseTlv(tlv.Value, tlv.subTlv);

        }
    }
}
```

Here is a utility class that contains some functions used in the class above. It is included for the sake of clarity how it works.

```
class Util
{
    public static string getHexString(byte[] arr)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(arr.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in arr)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    public static byte[] getBytes(String str)
    {
        byte[] result = new byte[str.Length >> 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = (byte)Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static int getInt(byte[] data, int offset, int length)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            result = (result << 8) | data[offset + i];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this parsing code.  It saved me a lot of work.  Very concise.

Comment: Thanks for this. Works great. For future reference, I found one bug here though. In your `BerTlv` class, `parseTlv` function, `BerTlv tlv = new BerTlv(tag, length, i - length, rawData);` should be `BerTlv tlv = new BerTlv(tag, length, rawData.Length - length, rawData);`.