# How to adapt public/private RSA keys of C# for using them as in Java?

Tags: java, c#, cryptography, rsa

I have some server that provides access to data by cryptographic API. I need to write client in C# that can create requests to server and read responses from.

For doing it I need to create public and private RSA keys and convert them to bytes array. I had the working example in java:

```
    java.security.KeyPairjava.security.KeyPair keypair = keyGen.genKeyPair();

    byte[] pubKeyBytes = keypair.getPublic().getEncoded();
    byte[] privKeyBytes = keypair.getPrivate().getEncoded();
```

I tried to do the same with C# in .NET:

```
    RSACryptoServiceProvider keyPair = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
    var publicKey = keyPair.ExportParameters(false);
    var privateKey = keyPair.ExportParameters(true);
```

And I don't know how to do it. I have D, Dp, DQ, InverseQ, Modulus, Exponent as properties of publicKey and privateKey, but in java sample those key looks like single united keys. Which one of D, Dp, DQ, InverseQ, Modulus, Exponent I should use for my task? What the way to do the same as in java example, but in C#?

Comment: What do you need to do with the bytes?  Send them to another C# program on Windows? Send them to Java?  Just save them and load them on the same computer?

Comment: To create an encrypted request to third-party service. This service provides an algorithm that describes how to do it. The algorithm is described in the document with 49 pages. Keys as bytes is necessary to implement this algorithm.

Comment: `ExportCspBlob` likely isn’t the answer you want, then. You probably want to look up SubjectPublicKeyInfo and PKCS8. (Or maybe just RSAPublicKey and RSAPrivateKey if it’s RSA-only). If there’s not a better answer by the time I have something other than a phone available I’ll try something better than this hint :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Key.html#getFormat() the default for a public key encoding is X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo and for a private key is PKCS#8 PrivateKeyInfo.

There are a number of questions (like [Correctly create RSACryptoServiceProvider from public key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41808094/6535399)) on creating RSAParameters from a SubjectPublicKeyInfo, but not as many for the reverse.

If you're creating your key via RSACryptoServiceProvider then the new key will always have an exponent value of 0x010001, which means the only variable sized piece of data that you have to contend with is the modulus value.  The reason that this is important is that a SubjectPublicKeyInfo is (almost always) encoded in DER (defined by [ITU-T X.690](http://www.itu.int/itu-t/recommendations/rec.aspx?rec=X.690)), which uses length-prefixed values.  The ASN.1 ([ITU-T X.680](http://www.itu.int/itu-t/recommendations/rec.aspx?rec=X.680)) is defined in [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1) as

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
    algorithm            AlgorithmIdentifier,
    subjectPublicKey     BIT STRING  }
```

The encoded value for the AlgorithmIdentifier for RSA is

```
30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01 05 00
```

(aka SEQUENCE([OID("1.2.840.113549.1.1.1")](http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.2.840.113549.1.1.1), NULL))

The value for `subjectPublicKey` depends on the algorithm.  For RSA it's `RSAPublicKey`, defined in [RFC 3447](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#appendix-A.1.1) as

```
RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
    modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
    publicExponent    INTEGER   -- e }
```

The encoding for an INTEGER is 02 (then the length) then the signed big-endian value.  So, assuming that your Exponent value is `01 00 01` the encoded value is `02 03 01 00 01`.  The modulus length depends on the size of your key.

```
int modulusBytes = parameters.Modulus.Length;

if (parameters.Modulus[0] >= 0x80)
    modulusBytes++;
```

RSACryptoServiceProvider should always create keys that need the extra byte, but technically keys could exist which don't.  The reason we need it is that parameters.Modulus is an UNsigned big-endian encoding, and if the high bit is set then we would be encoding a negative number into the RSAPublicKey.  We fix that by inserting an 00 byte to keep the sign bit clear.

The length bytes for the modulus are slightly tricky.  If the modulus is representable in 127 bytes or fewer (RSA-1015 or smaller) then you just use one byte for that value.  Otherwise you need the smallest number of bytes to report the number, plus one.  That extra byte (the first one, actually) says how many bytes the length is.  So 128-255 is one byte, `81`. 256-65535 is two, so `82`.

We then need to wrap that into a BIT STRING value, which is easy (if we ignore the hard parts, since they're not relevant here).   And then wrap everything else up in a SEQUENCE, which is easy.

Quick and dirty, only works on a 2048-bit key with exponent=0x010001:

```
private static byte[] s_prefix =
{
    0x30, 0x82, 0x01, 0x22,
          0x30, 0x0D,
                0x06, 0x09, 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xF7, 0x0D, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01,
                0x05, 0x00,
          0x03, 0x82, 0x01, 0x0F,
                0x00,
                0x30, 0x82, 0x01, 0x0A,
                      0x02, 0x82, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00
};

private static byte[] s_suffix = { 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01 };

private static byte[] MakeSubjectPublicInfoEasy2048(RSA rsa)
{
    if (rsa.KeySize != 2048)
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(rsa));

    RSAParameters rsaParameters = rsa.ExportParameters(false);

    if (Convert.ToBase64String(rsaParameters.Exponent) != "AQAB")
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(rsa));
    }

    return s_prefix.Concat(rsaParameters.Modulus).Concat(s_suffix).ToArray();
}
```

Or, for a general-purpose response (that creates a lot of temporary byte[]s):

```
private static byte[] MakeTagLengthValue(byte tag, byte[] value, int index = 0, int length = -1)
{
    if (length == -1)
    {
        length = value.Length - index;
    }

    byte[] data;

    if (length < 0x80)
    {
        data = new byte[length + 2];
        data[1] = (byte)length;
    }
    else if (length <= 0xFF)
    {
        data = new byte[length + 3];
        data[1] = 0x81;
        data[2] = (byte)length;
    }
    else if (length <= 0xFFFF)
    {
        data = new byte[length + 4];
        data[1] = 0x82;
        data[2] = (byte)(length >> 8);
        data[3] = unchecked((byte)length);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Continue the pattern");
    }

    data[0] = tag;
    int dataOffset = data.Length - length;
    Buffer.BlockCopy(value, index, data, dataOffset, length);
    return data;
}

private static byte[] MakeInteger(byte[] unsignedBigEndianValue)
{
    if (unsignedBigEndianValue[0] >= 0x80)
    {
        byte[] tmp = new byte[unsignedBigEndianValue.Length + 1];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(unsignedBigEndianValue, 0, tmp, 1, unsignedBigEndianValue.Length);
        return MakeTagLengthValue(0x02, tmp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < unsignedBigEndianValue.Length; i++)
    {
        if (unsignedBigEndianValue[i] != 0)
        {
            if (unsignedBigEndianValue[i] >= 0x80)
            {
                i--;
            }

            return MakeTagLengthValue(0x02, unsignedBigEndianValue, i);
        }
    }

    // All bytes were 0, encode 0.
    return MakeTagLengthValue(0x02, unsignedBigEndianValue, 0, 1);
}

private static byte[] MakeSequence(params byte[][] data)
{
    return MakeTagLengthValue(0x30, data.SelectMany(a => a).ToArray());
}

private static byte[] MakeBitString(byte[] data)
{
    byte[] tmp = new byte[data.Length + 1];
    // Insert a 0x00 byte for the unused bit count value
    Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, tmp, 1, data.Length);
    return MakeTagLengthValue(0x03, tmp);
}

private static byte[] s_rsaAlgorithmId = new byte[] { 0x30, 0x0D, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xF7, 0x0D, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00 };

private static byte[] ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(RSA rsa)
{
    RSAParameters parameters = rsa.ExportParameters(false);

    return MakeSequence(
        s_rsaAlgorithmId,
        MakeBitString(
            MakeSequence(
                MakeInteger(parameters.Modulus),
                MakeInteger(parameters.Exponent))));
}
```

You shouldn't really need the encoded private key.  But, if you really do, you need the general-purpose approach because there's a lot of room for variability in the private key data.

`PrivateKeyInfo` is defined in [RFC 5208](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208#section-5) as

```
PrivateKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
  version                   Version,
  privateKeyAlgorithm       PrivateKeyAlgorithmIdentifier,
  privateKey                PrivateKey,
  attributes           [0]  IMPLICIT Attributes OPTIONAL }

Version ::= INTEGER

PrivateKeyAlgorithmIdentifier ::= AlgorithmIdentifier

PrivateKey ::= OCTET STRING

Attributes ::= SET OF Attribute
```

It also says the current version number is 0.

The octet string of the private key is defined by the algorithm.  For RSA we see in RFC 3447, along with `RSAPublicKey`:

```
RSAPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
  version           Version,
  modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
  publicExponent    INTEGER,  -- e
  privateExponent   INTEGER,  -- d
  prime1            INTEGER,  -- p
  prime2            INTEGER,  -- q
  exponent1         INTEGER,  -- d mod (p-1)
  exponent2         INTEGER,  -- d mod (q-1)
  coefficient       INTEGER,  -- (inverse of q) mod p
  otherPrimeInfos   OtherPrimeInfos OPTIONAL }
```

Ignore `otherPrimeInfos`.  It doesn't, and shouldn't ever, apply. Therefore the version number to use is 0.

Taking utility methods already defined, we get the rest by

```
private static byte[] MakeOctetString(byte[] data)
{
    return MakeTagLengthValue(0x04, data);
}

private static byte[] s_integerZero = new byte[] { 0x02, 0x01, 0x00 };

private static byte[] ExportPrivateKeyInfo(RSA rsa)
{
    RSAParameters parameters = rsa.ExportParameters(true);

    return MakeSequence(
        s_integerZero,
        s_rsaAlgorithmId,
        MakeOctetString(
            MakeSequence(
                s_integerZero,
                MakeInteger(parameters.Modulus),
                MakeInteger(parameters.Exponent),
                MakeInteger(parameters.D),
                MakeInteger(parameters.P),
                MakeInteger(parameters.Q),
                MakeInteger(parameters.DP),
                MakeInteger(parameters.DQ),
                MakeInteger(parameters.InverseQ))));
}
```

Making all of this easier is on the feature roadmap for .NET Core (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20414 - doesn't say export, but where there's an import there's usually an export :))

Save your output to a file and you can check it with `openssl rsa -inform der -pubin -text -in pub.key` and `openssl rsa -inform der -text -in priv.key`

Comment: I need to send public key (encrypted with hmac password which is known only for me as a client of this service) in header of http request. Response is encrypted by my public key from header and I need to decrypt it. I know that keypair.getPublic().getEncoded() works correctly in this algorithm, but it is java not c#. Can I decrypt response by key in case when I use public key calculated by way from your example?

Comment: @MiraiMann I don’t follow. HMAC isn’t an encryption algorithm. But `ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo` is the same as `getPublic().getEncoded()`, and `ExportPrivateKeyInfo()` is the same as `getPrivate().getEncoded()`.

Comment: Client sends RSA key and HMAC of this key. Server calculates HMAC of received key and compares it with received HMAC for verification. Anyway it was unnecessary information. Sorry for that. I will try to use your solution tomorrow at the office. Thank you.

Comment: I used code from your sample and my generated public key has been verified. As result, I have encrypted response and unsuccessfully trying to decrypt it with private key. I use rsa.Decrypt(src, true/* I tried false too*/) and has exception 'The data to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this modulus of 256 bytes.' Content size is 2519609 bytes. It looks like I can't decrypt it by this way. How to decrypt response by my private key?

Comment: I think my last comment is offtopic, and other question. I accept your answer because the current question is closed.

Comment: @MiraiMann RSA is only defined to encrypt data the size of the key (in bytes). Usually what is encrypted is a symmetric (e.g. AES) key that encrypts the rest of the data. But you’re now in a different question, so you should ask a new one (if that hint wasn’t sufficient). Assuming you have something working in Java you should say what that code is.

Comment: Posted other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328317/how-to-decrypt-source-encrypted-with-rsa1-5-a256cbc-hs512-when-size-of-it-is-m

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`ExportCspBlob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.exportcspblob(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider keyPair = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
var publicKey = keyPair.ExportCspBlob(false);
var privateKey = keyPair.ExportCspBlob(true);
```

`ExportParameters` exports the specific parameters from which the keys themselves can be calculated. For more information about those parameters, see the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)).

Comment: Looks like exactly what I need. But I'll implement my client to check that is it works and after that accept your answer.

Comment: I checked and it is not the same.