# How to use the public key generated by using PHP on the server?

Tags: c#, php, laravel, openssl, rsa

**On the server**, I have an PHP script (Laravel) that can generate RSA key pairs, flash them into the session, and return a base64 encoded public key, which will be used in my windows application to encrypt the password, and the key is created by calling the **openssl_pkey_new** function:

```
// get RSA key pairs
public function generateRSAKeyPairTest(Request $request)
{
    $t = $this->microtime_float();

    $res = openssl_pkey_new();
    openssl_pkey_export($res, $privkeyraw);
    $d= openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
    $pubkeyraw = $d['key'];
    $pubkey = base64_encode($pubkeyraw);
    $privkey = base64_encode($privkeyraw);
    $request->session()->flash('privkey', $privkey);
    $request->session()->flash('pubkey', $pubkey);

    $tdiff = $this->microtime_float() - $t;
    $keypair = array('pubkey'  => $pubkey,'diff' => $tdiff);

    return response()->json($keypair);
}

// decode the encryted string
public function decryptRSATest(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->session()->has('privkey')) 
    {
        $privkey = $request->session()->get('privkey', 'default value');
        $resPriv = openssl_pkey_get_private(base64_decode($privkey));

        $encrypted_text_base64 = $request->encrypted_text;
        $outval = '-';
        $encrypted_text = base64_decode($encrypted_text_base64);
        openssl_private_decrypt($encrypted_text, $outval, $resPriv);
        return response()->json(
            [
                 'decoded_text_from_clit'=>$outval
            ]
        );
    }
    return response()->json(["error"=>"private key does not exist!"]);
}
```

then in my **windows application** (C#), I get the json from server and retrieve the public key

```
    var data = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeyStringBase64);
    var publicKeyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    var pkStr = publicKeyRaw.Replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "").Replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
    var publicKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pkStr);
```

the **publicKeyRaw** is like following (PKCS#8 format):

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
>   MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEArwg6U1EET7OSbLO7UUZh
>   7p8ODYY4kXUd5S1Z/qexG5IqpNflrdQbpVh+8KWNi83oidAUjWEb050Rl3AuY/E6
>   7hYlEdUvI9pevmBpjjU1GktzQsDsbva3THHSpTZXPlctnFnuz0b5hVu1nUETmbGF
>   fSbslZet3pbKcK5KGnJpm6v6OQGpvgQjyNWF16HjUD4/x1rAL2aDNOZZED+FNJcC
>   hNmdK1A8nECk1JoTTdiK7r0EXMWxdVjEaSkAsvi7ywKi7ZESWwS1JmRuIJ5ZPiRx
>   Fvur1tgaiomEZ+9oDpk1+bwDenrERYgBxw2L6Rw0CwuyinhwYfIbWkNmy4cAiZVx 
>   KwIDAQAB
>   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

I tried to use RSAParameters, but whether the Modulus is the raw byte array (**data**) or the array converted from the stripped string (**publicKey**), the encryptedText encrypted by using RSACryptoServiceProvider's Encrypt method cannot be decrypted by **openssl_private_decrypt** on the server.

```
var rsaInfo = new RSAParameters()
{
    Exponent = new byte[] { 1, 0, 1 },
    Modulus = data, // publicKey 
};

var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
csp.ImportParameters(rsaInfo);
var password = "testing-passsword!";
var hash = csp.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password), false);
var encryptedText = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
```

I guess that RSACryptoServiceProvider does not encrypt the password correctly, so what is the correct way to use this key string (publicKeyRaw ) with the RSACryptoServiceProvider ?

### **[Update]**

After doing a lot of searching work on google, the prolem becomes clear (just the same as what @James Reinstate Monica Polk mentions):
the key generated by using openssl_pkey_new() is, by default, in **PKCS#8** format, while RSACryptoServiceProvider only accepts the key in **PKCS#1 v1.5** format. Such incompatibility caused this problem.

so, do you have any solutions for this?

Comment: As far as I know .NET doesn't support the public key format you are using. And it's unclear where you're getting `data` from in `Modulus = data`.

Comment: `data` is base64 encoded public key, passed from server via a HTTP request and parsed by josn parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution from this post: [Correctly create RSACryptoServiceProvider from public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808094/correctly-create-rsacryptoserviceprovider-from-public-key)

there are many things we need to take care of when using the **RSAPrameters** class.

1. it is recommended to encode the public key by using
   **base64_encode** on the server so that it could be passed to the client in a json string. And I use phpseclib instead of the openssl.
   to genereate the PKCS#1 format public key
2. In C#，decode the base64 encoded string into a readable public key
       string, which has a format as follows:

> ```
>         -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
>         base64 encoded data
>          -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
> ```

3. In C#, retrieve the public key data and extract the modulus and
   public exponent byte arrays. In this step, we should pay a
   particular attention to **Modulus** in the **RSAParameters** class,
   when we fill in the Modulus, we should **skip the fist byte**, which
   is **0x00**. I implemented a simple but not complete decoder as follows:

```
public static RSAParameters GetRSAParametersFromPublicKey(string publicKeyString)
{
            // publicKeyString should have following format:

            // -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY---- -
            // base64 encoded data
            // -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY---- -

            var pubicKeyContentString = publicKeyString.Replace("-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
                .Replace("-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
                .Replace("\r", "")
                .Replace("\n", "")
                .Replace(@"\/", "/");
            var publicKeyArray = Convert.FromBase64String(pubicKeyContentString);

            var mask = 0x7F;
            var skipCount = 0;
            var rsaParameters = new RSAParameters();
            for (int i = 0; i < publicKeyArray.Length; i=skipCount)
            {
                var tag = publicKeyArray[i];
                var lengthLength = publicKeyArray[i + 1];
                var length = Convert.ToInt32(lengthLength);
                skipCount += 2;
                if (lengthLength > mask)
                {
                    var lengthBit = lengthLength & mask;
                    var lengthBytes = publicKeyArray.Skip(skipCount).Take(lengthBit).ToArray();
                    skipCount += lengthBit;
                    length = BitConverter.ToInt16(lengthBytes.Reverse().ToArray(),0);
                }
                if (tag == 0x02)
                {
                    // both modulus and public exponent start with 0x02: integer
                    // therefore, 0x02 is the only tag we are interested in
                    var valueBytes = publicKeyArray.Skip(skipCount).Take(length).ToArray();
                    if (valueBytes[0] == 0x00)
                    {
                        // a valid DER has a leading byte 0x00
                        rsaParameters.Modulus = valueBytes.Skip(1).ToArray();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rsaParameters.Exponent = valueBytes;
                    }
                    skipCount += length;
                }
            }
            return rsaParameters;
        }
```

and here is a function that encrypt the input plainText with input base64 encoded public key string

```
public static string Cryptography(string plainText, string publicKeyStringBase64)
{
    var publicKey = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeyStringBase64);
    var publicKeyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(publicKey);
    var rsaInfo = GetRSAParametersFromPublicKey(publicKeyRaw);
    if (rsaInfo.Modulus != null && rsaInfo.Exponent != null)
    {
        var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        csp.ImportParameters(rsaInfo);
        var hash = csp.Encrypt(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText), false);
        var encryptedText = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(hash));

        return encryptedText;
    }
    return "!!error!!";
}
```

4. On the server, I'd like to use phpseclib instead to generate a PKCS#1 key pair and perform the decoding (laravel):

```
    use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;

    public function decryptRSATest(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->session()->has('privkey')) 
        {
            $privkeybase64 = $request->session()->get('privkey', 'default value');
            str_replace(['\/', '\n'], ['/', ''], $privkeybase64);
            $privkey = base64_decode($privkeybase64);

            $rsa = new RSA();
            $received = str_replace(['\/', '\n',"\0",'\\'], ['/', '', '',""], $request->encrypted_text);
            $rsa->loadKey($privkey);
            $rsa->setEncryptionMode(RSA::ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
            $decrypt_text2 = $rsa->decrypt(base64_decode($received));
            $decrypt_text2 = str_replace("\0",'',$decrypt_text2);

            return response()->json(
                [
                     'decoded_text_from_clit' => $decrypt_text2
                ]
            );
        }
        return response()->json(["error"=>"private key does not exist!"]);
    }
```

Moreover, if we just need the modulus and the exponent instead of a complete public key, we can just pass the modulus and exponent to the client (base64_encoded):

```
            // PHP - Server end
            $modulus_base64 = base64_encode($rsa->modulus);
            $exponent_base64 = base64_encode($rsa->exponent);
```

and in the C#, it might be a little bit tough to correctly decode them, here is a code snippet:

```
        // C# - Client end
        var modulus = Convert.FromBase64String(modulusStringBase64);
        var exponent = Convert.FromBase64String(exponentStringBase64);
        var modulusRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(modulus);
        var exponentRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(exponent);
        var bigIntegerModulus = BigInteger.Parse(modulusRaw);
        var bigIntegerExponent = BigInteger.Parse(exponentRaw);
        var exponentArray = bigIntegerExponent.ToByteArray();
        var modulusArray = bigIntegerModulus.ToByteArray();
```

and some useful online tools:

[base64 decoder](https://www.base64decode.net/)

[ASN 1 decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js/)

[Json Viewer](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer)

Hope this could be helpful for you.

Comment: `str_replace(['\/', '\n'], ['/', ''], $privkeybase64);` is oddly dangling in your snippet.  Did you mean to say `$privkeybase64 = str_replace(['\/', '\n'], ['/', ''], $privkeybase64);`?