# Use PEM encoded RSA private key in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, rsa, private-key

I have a private key which looks like this:

> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
>   **Some private key data**
>   -----END RSA PRIVA

I need to use this key in my C# project, but I couldn't find any example how to use key in this format. Thanks

Comment: So what's the question? Did you try anything? In what kind of medium is the key provided to you?

Comment: are you trying to ship with this key?  or read it from disk, supplied by the user?  or ...?

Comment: I receive the key from a web service. I need to use it to decrypt encrypted data, but I don't know how to use it in .NET. I remember .NET has it's own private key format which is xml based...

Answer (score 17):

1. step 1 get "Some private key data" content.remove -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----, Removes all line symbols("\n");
2. step 2. parse key to RSA.

```cs
private RSACryptoServiceProvider CreateRsaProviderFromPrivateKey(string privateKey)
{
    var privateKeyBits = System.Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);

    var RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    var RSAparams = new RSAParameters();

    using (BinaryReader binr = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(privateKeyBits)))
    {
        byte bt = 0;
        ushort twobytes = 0;
        twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
        if (twobytes == 0x8130)
            binr.ReadByte();
        else if (twobytes == 0x8230)
            binr.ReadInt16();
        else
            throw new Exception("Unexpected value read binr.ReadUInt16()");

        twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
        if (twobytes != 0x0102)
            throw new Exception("Unexpected version");

        bt = binr.ReadByte();
        if (bt != 0x00)
            throw new Exception("Unexpected value read binr.ReadByte()");

        RSAparams.Modulus = binr.ReadBytes(GetIntegerSize(binr));
        RSAparams.Exponent = binr.ReadBytes(GetIntegerSize(binr));
        RSAparams.D = binr.ReadBytes(GetIntegerSize(binr));
        RSAparams.P = binr.ReadBytes(GetIntegerSize(binr));
        RSAparams.Q = binr.ReadBytes(GetIntegerSize(binr));
        RSAparams.DP = binr.ReadBytes(GetIntegerSize(binr));
        RSAparams.DQ = binr.ReadBytes(GetIntegerSize(binr));
        RSAparams.InverseQ = binr.ReadBytes(GetIntegerSize(binr));
    }

    RSA.ImportParameters(RSAparams);
    return RSA;
}

private int GetIntegerSize(BinaryReader binr)
{
    byte bt = 0;
    byte lowbyte = 0x00;
    byte highbyte = 0x00;
    int count = 0;
    bt = binr.ReadByte();
    if (bt != 0x02)
        return 0;
    bt = binr.ReadByte();

    if (bt == 0x81)
        count = binr.ReadByte();
    else
        if (bt == 0x82)
        {
            highbyte = binr.ReadByte();
            lowbyte = binr.ReadByte();
            byte[] modint = { lowbyte, highbyte, 0x00, 0x00 };
            count = BitConverter.ToInt32(modint, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            count = bt;
        }

    while (binr.ReadByte() == 0x00)
    {
        count -= 1;
    }
    binr.BaseStream.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.Current);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: My question is: how should I have known this method? :) Why it isn't still available in Microsoft RSA library?

Answer (score 2):

All major .NET/C# Cryptography libraries (like BouncyCastle, or SecureBlackbox [commercial]) should support this format, as well as operations with loaded key (encryption/decryption/signing/verification).

Comment: To clarify things, .NET base class library doesn't support PEM format right? :(

Comment: In PEM - not. However, you can manually strip out header, base64-decode data, and got data for PKCS8PrivateKeyInfo. See this question for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243646/how-to-read-a-pem-rsa-private-key-from-net

Answer (score 2):

Though an older post I though I'd glue my own answer to this question as I bumped into the same challenge earlier this year.
I wrote a library for the handling of PEM keys, encryption, decryption, signing and signature verification.
There's an complete example solution attached to it (Load-Encrypt-Decrypt-Save), so you should be able to be up running in no-time.

https://github.com/jrnker/CSharp-easy-RSA-PEM

Cheers,
Christoffer

Comment: Tried your code. My key is in PEM format, the cipher text has length 512 chars (Base64)  and priv key is 1588 chars (Base64)/2048 bytes. Trying to decrypt this cipher text with private key the function:
```byte[] DecryptBytes(string inputString, RSACryptoServiceProvider key)```
throws the following exception,
```The data to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this modulus of 256 bytes```
FYI, by putting a breakpoint I can see that the base64BlockSize = 258 bytes
Can you please assist me in fixing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The following article I wrote about digital signature gives a solution in c# (no additional library needed). The code shows how a RSA private key in PEM format can be converted to the XML format used by the .NET RSACryptoServiceProvider Class.

With Atlando Crypto Currency Geo Service your identity is stored in your browser after registration. At each request a contract with us is signed and encrypted by this identity with your private key. This article explains how it works.

Code below gives an implementation in C# (RSACryptoServiceProvider Class) of the authentication process through comparison of the original and a signed version. The modulus comes from the RSA public key in PEM format (exponent AQAB).

```
  private static bool Verify(string original, string signature, string modulus)
  {
    SHA256Managed sha = new SHA256Managed();

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(original);
    byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(bytes);

    sha.Clear();

    byte[] signed = new byte[signature.Length/2];

    for (int i = 0; i < signature.Length; i += 2)
    {
      signed[i/2] = Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToInt32(signature.Substring(i, 2), 16));
    }

    string key = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>" + modulus + "</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";

    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
      rsa.FromXmlString(key);

      RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter RSADeformatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(rsa);

      RSADeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");

      return RSADeformatter.VerifySignature(hash, signed);
    }
  }


  public static string Modulus(string pem)
  {
    byte[] x509der = Convert.FromBase64String(pem.Replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "").Replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", ""));

    byte[] seqOID = { 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xF7, 0x0D, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 };

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(x509der);
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(ms);

    if (reader.ReadByte() == 0x30) ReadASNLength(reader); //skip the size
    else return null;

    int identifierSize = 0; //total length of Object Identifier section

    if (reader.ReadByte() == 0x30) identifierSize = ReadASNLength(reader);
    else return null;

    if (reader.ReadByte() == 0x06) //is the next element an object identifier?
    {
      int oidLength = ReadASNLength(reader);
      byte[] oidBytes = new byte[oidLength];
      reader.Read(oidBytes, 0, oidBytes.Length);

      if (oidBytes.SequenceEqual(seqOID) == false) return null; //is the object identifier rsaEncryption PKCS#1?

      int remainingBytes = identifierSize - 2 - oidBytes.Length;
      reader.ReadBytes(remainingBytes);
    }

    if (reader.ReadByte() == 0x03) //is the next element a bit string?
    {
      ReadASNLength(reader); //skip the size
      reader.ReadByte(); //skip unused bits indicator
      if (reader.ReadByte() == 0x30)
      {
        ReadASNLength(reader); //skip the size
        if (reader.ReadByte() == 0x02) //is it an integer?
        {
          int modulusSize = ReadASNLength(reader);
          byte[] modulus = new byte[modulusSize];
          reader.Read(modulus, 0, modulus.Length);
          if (modulus[0] == 0x00) //strip off the first byte if it's 0
          {
            byte[] tempModulus = new byte[modulus.Length - 1];
            Array.Copy(modulus, 1, tempModulus, 0, modulus.Length - 1);
            modulus = tempModulus;
          }

          if (reader.ReadByte() == 0x02) //is it an integer?
          {
            int exponentSize = ReadASNLength(reader);
            byte[] exponent = new byte[exponentSize];
            reader.Read(exponent, 0, exponent.Length);

            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = new RSAParameters();
            RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = modulus;
            RSAKeyInfo.Exponent = exponent;
            rsa.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
            return rsa.ToXmlString(false).Replace("<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>", "").Replace("</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>", "");
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return null;
  }


  public static int ReadASNLength(BinaryReader reader)
  {//Note: this method only reads lengths up to 4 bytes long as this is satisfactory for the majority of situations.
    int length = reader.ReadByte();
    if ((length & 0x00000080) == 0x00000080) //is the length greater than 1 byte
    {
      int count = length & 0x0000000f;
      byte[] lengthBytes = new byte[4];
      reader.Read(lengthBytes, 4 - count, count);
      Array.Reverse(lengthBytes); //
      length = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBytes, 0);
    }
    return length;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to transform the private key to the form of RSA parameters using [Bouncy Castle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle/) library. Then you need to pass the RSA parameters to the RSA algorithm as the private key. Lastly, you use the [JWT](https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt) library to encode and sign the token.

```
    public string GenerateJWTToken(string rsaPrivateKey)
    {
        var rsaParams = GetRsaParameters(rsaPrivateKey);
        var encoder = GetRS256JWTEncoder(rsaParams);

        // create the payload according to your need
        var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "iss", ""},
            { "sub", "" },
            // and other key-values 
        };

        var token = encoder.Encode(payload, new byte[0]);

        return token;
    }

    private static IJwtEncoder GetRS256JWTEncoder(RSAParameters rsaParams)
    {
        var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        csp.ImportParameters(rsaParams);

        var algorithm = new RS256Algorithm(csp, csp);
        var serializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
        var urlEncoder = new JwtBase64UrlEncoder();
        var encoder = new JwtEncoder(algorithm, serializer, urlEncoder);

        return encoder;
    }

    private static RSAParameters GetRsaParameters(string rsaPrivateKey)
    {
        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rsaPrivateKey);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
            {
                // use Bouncy Castle to convert the private key to RSA parameters
                var pemReader = new PemReader(sr);
                var keyPair = pemReader.ReadObject() as AsymmetricCipherKeyPair;
                return DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(keyPair.Private as RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters);
            }
        }
    }
```

ps: the RSA private key should have the following format:

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

{base64 formatted value}

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----