# Sign text in C# with SHA256

Tags: c#, node.js, cryptography, sign

I have some code in nodejs and I am trying to replicate in in C# but I can't seem to find a simple solution like the nodejs one:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var privateKey = '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n'+
      /// key removed
'-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----';

var publicKey = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n'+
      /// key removed
'-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';

// sign string
var signer = crypto.createSign('sha256');
signer.update('ugus-dev/logo.png');
var sign = signer.sign(privateKey,'base64');
console.log(sign);

// verify signature 
var verifier = crypto.createVerify('sha256');
verifier.update('ugus-dev/logo.png');
var ver = verifier.verify(publicKey, sign,'base64'); 

console.log(ver); // true if signature matches.
```

Basically i will be singing a string in C# and then verifying the signature of the string in nodeJS with the obove code for verify.

So I am looking for an equvalent of:

```
// sign string
var signer = crypto.createSign('sha256');
signer.update('ugus-dev/logo.png');
var sign = signer.sign(privateKey,'base64');
```

in C#.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644926/use-pem-encoded-rsa-private-key-in-net/32150537#32150537

Comment: this did it for me, specifically the answer from Chris.J, Thanks bartonjs!

Answer (score 0):

A head start:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

SHA256 mySHA=SHA256.Create();
string myText="yourText";
byte[] byteArr=Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myText);
byte[] hash=mySHA.ComputeHash(byteArr);

string res=BitConverter.ToString(hash);
//Or 
string res=Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
```

Comment: answering my own comment: mySHA.LoadPrivateFromXml(@"C:\privateKey.xml");
mySHA.LoadPublicFromXml(@"C:\publicKey.xml");

Comment: This should help you.[link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2008/06/25/how-to-sign-and-verify-the-signature-with-net-and-a-certificate-c/)