# Https Post with .crt and .key

Tags: c#, php, asp.net-core, payment-gateway, nopcommerce-4.0

I am sorry if it is duplicate. I see a couple of post over the internet about this topic. But do not get any appropriate solution. I am working at nopcommerce 4.0, which is run on the .net core but the targeted framework is 4.x.x. I am developing a payment plugin which needs secure connection with .crt and .key files. The payment method provider sends a php file which is working as expected. Below is the sample code

```
function ProcessRequest($curl_post_data,$service_url,$proxy,$proxyauth)
{
$output = '';
$certfile       = '/createorder.crt';
$keyfile        = '/createorder.key';
$cert_password = '';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 ); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, getcwd() . $certfile );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, getcwd() . $keyfile );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
   echo $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
}
$cblcz = json_decode($output, true );
return $cblcz;
}

$proxy ="";
$proxyauth ="";
$postDatatoken = '{
"password": "123456Aa",
"userName": "test"
}';
$serviceUrltoken ="";
$serviceUrltoken= 'https://sandbox.thecitybank.com:7788/transaction/token';
$cblcz = ProcessRequest($postDatatoken,$serviceUrltoken,$proxy,$proxyauth);
```

I can not convert this curl to http post. I tried below link

[PHP/Curl-SSL operations alternative in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159518/php-curl-ssl-operations-alternative-in-c-sharp) and others but do not get any work around.

Do not work. For openssl it is throwing dependency are not loaded. Here is my c# code

```
try
            {
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                       | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

                var certPath = Path.Combine(CommonHelper.MapPath("~/Plugins/Payments.CityBankApi/"), "createorder.crt");
                var keyPath = Path.Combine(CommonHelper.MapPath("~/Plugins/Payments.CityBankApi/"), "createorder.key");


               string certificateText = File.ReadAllText(certPath);
                string privateKeyText = File.ReadAllText(keyPath);

                ICertificateProvider provider = new CertificateFromFileProvider(certificateText, privateKeyText);
                //X509Certificate certificate = provider.Certificate;

                string accessTokenUrl = "https://sandbox.thecitybank.com:7788/transaction/token";

                var requestUrl = new Uri(accessTokenUrl);
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(accessTokenUrl);
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Method = "POST";

                request.ClientCertificates.Add(provider.Certificate);


                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    string json = "{\"userName\":\"test\"," +
                                  "\"password\":\"123456Aa\"}";

                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct. But make sure you have **valid certificate**. If the certification is not correct it will through an exception. Check your exception message and try to detect exact error. OR post your error message here.

moreover you should add

```
request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (e,r,c,n) => true;
```

Comment: Actually, you are correct the remote certificate was not valid, if we see curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); and curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE); lines it is by force false.