# Encrypt password by using Public Key (.pem) file

Tags: c#, public-key-encryption

Now I have a Public Key(.pem) file and password to encrypt.

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----

.....
...
...

-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

I would like to get byte[] values for encrypted password. 
It doesn't get any error but return byte[] values is seem to wrong.

**Below are coding current my using one, pls help me or advise me if I'm going wrong.**

Really appreciate for your help!!

```
private static UnicodeEncoding _encoder = new UnicodeEncoding();

public byte[] getPem(string pemFile, string password)
        {
            byte[] encryptData;

            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] Exponent = { 1, 0, 1 };

            RSAParameters rsaParam = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
            rsaParam.Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String(File.ReadAllText(pemFile).Replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "").Replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", ""));

            rsaParam.Exponent = Exponent;

            rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParam);
            var dataToEncrypt = _encoder.GetBytes(password);
            encryptData = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false);

            return encryptData;
        }
```

Comment: You can use bouncycastle for reading the pem file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243646/how-to-read-a-pem-rsa-private-key-from-net

Comment: thank for your comment! but it's using Private Key & to encrypt that key file. I would like to know is to make encrypt a string by using "Public Key" file (.pem).

Comment: Yeah, didn't say it's a duplicate of your question. Just think you can borrow ways to read out the .pem file correctly because I don't think it just Base64 :)

Comment: Try to 'Replace("\r\n",String.Empty);'.
Also, try just to read all strings except the first and the last.