# How to set pkcs8 private key in X509Certificate

Tags: c#, x509certificate, dotnet-httpclient, mutual-authentication, pkcs#8

I am writing client for mutual-tls communication in C# (actually clr / cli). I am facing issue while doing it. When I am running it.

I have written a following code in my post method:--

```
    System::Net::ServicePointManager::SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType::Tls12;

    HttpClient^ httpClient;
    Task<HttpResponseMessage ^> ^ resultTask;

    WebRequestHandler ^ clientHandler = gcnew WebRequestHandler();
    clientHandler->ClientCertificates->Add(state->ptrClientCert);//add certificate of client provided by server
    clientHandler->AuthenticationLevel = System::Net::Security::AuthenticationLevel::MutualAuthRequired;
    httpClient = gcnew HttpClient(clientHandler);

            httpClient->DefaultRequestHeaders->Accept->Add("application/octet-stream");

            HttpContent ^ httpContent = gcnew ByteArrayContent(state->postBody);
    httpContent->Headers->ContentType = gcnew MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
  resultTask = httpClient->PostAsync(state->httpRequest, httpContent);   
    if (resultTask->Wait(DefaultTimeOut))
    //wait for finish
    {
    HttpResponseMessage ^ response = resultTask->Result;
    SetResponse(response, state->darkClientRef, state->ptrHttprequest, state->appLog);
    }
```

Now this code is not working as it is throwing socket exception that " Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcefully closed by remote host connection". My understanding says, that possible reason can be that I am not able to set my private key in request as client certificate provided by server only has public key.

Now my question is that how can I set my private key (which is in PKCS8 format) in this request ?

I am using .Net framework 4.5.2.

## EDIT:

After my research, I have found that issue is, I am not setting my private key in my X509Certificate. I am receiving private key from different component. As per my understanding, the following way would be right way to set private key.

```
WebRequestHandler ^ clientHandler = gcnew WebRequestHandler();
            X509Certificates::X509Certificate2^ modCert = gcnew X509Certificates::X509Certificate2(state->ptrClientCert);
RSACryptoServiceProvider ^ rsaProvider;
rsaProvider = RSAConverter::DecodePrivateKeyInfo(privateKey); 
            modCert->PrivateKey = rsaProvider;
            clientHandler->ClientCertificates->Add(modCert);
```

I have implemented DecodePrivateKeyInfo function using following links :--

http://www.jensign.com/opensslkey/opensslkey.cs

But this function fails to parse my private key (which is created by openssl) as it fails in CompareBytearrays function.
Can somebody help me that how can I set this PKCS8 format key in X509 certificate ?

Comment: I am looking for answers and I have found that some people has posted that Ststem.Net.HttpClient (my application is windows application and OS version is windows 7) does not support TLS1.2 ? Is it ? In that case Can we use HTTPWebRequest ?

Comment: It seems that I am ending in a issue where I have to convert my PKCS8 private key in to RSAProvider interface in order to set it in X509Certificate. Key has been generated using EVP_PKEY2PKCS8 function of OpenSSL.

I have sued following links to convert the key but they did not work.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151376/public-key-chunked-encryption-with-c-method-to-decrypt

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243646/how-to-read-a-pem-rsa-private-key-from-net

Can someone direct me the right example which I can use to convert the key.

Comment: Where you able to finally get it working?