# Data Signed in C# is different compare to openssl_sign in PHP

Tags: c#, openssl

Below is the c# coding I used to sign data but I couldn't get back the same signed data compare to openssl_sign in php

```
     public static string SignData(string clearText)
        {
            var bytesToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clearText);

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("./keys/private.pem");
            PemReader pr = new PemReader(sr);
            var keyPair = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)pr.ReadObject();
            var rsaParameters = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(keyPair);

            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

            var sig = rsa.SignData(bytesToEncrypt, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(sig);

        }
```

PHP

```
    public static function encrypt($timestamp, $url, $datajson){
    
        
        if(openssl_sign($signatureRawData, $x_mb_signature, static::Private_key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256)){
            $output = base64_encode($x_mb_signature);
        }

        return $output;
    }
```

Comment: Where do `$signatureRawData` and `static::Private_key` come from? What data types are they?

Comment: private_key sample as below and for my C# are refer to the same private key as well, when using openssl_sign from ssl is getting the correct signed data(verified by vendor side) but when using the c# signed function is getting the wrong 1

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
key content
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

sample signatureRawData  data

POST;https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

Comment: If you have .NET 5+ you can try `var rsa = RSA.Create(); rsa.ImportFromPem(YourPrivateKeyString);` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243646/how-to-read-a-pem-rsa-private-key-from-net

Comment: just tried.. same as result before changed it